# Spring cloud Zipkin server data retention period

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Spring cloud Zipkin to trace calls with sample percentage 0.4. I am not using any persistent storage like MySQL or Cassandra. Could you please let me know how to set data retention period in Zipkin server e.g. I want to check only 6 hours/1 day data.

Or if I can set max span count

Answer (score 0):

With Spring boot **Dalston.SR3** (which uses open zipkin 1.28) you can achieve this by setting property **zipkin.storage.mem.max-spans=xxx** This will limit the number of spans and discard old ones.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: This applies only when spans are stored in memory. It's not a solution to limit storage in Cassandra or Mysql.